# How to solve the error : polls is not defined by django beginner tutorial

Tags: python, django, localhost

[image]

every time I run it to get polls application I get that it's not defined why??

[image]

and would you tell me please whats wrong with my code and whenever I put from . import views I don't know why it takes import the module, not the dot.

Note: As well I tried to turn the Debug off or turn it to false and I still get the same error.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you post code from your `mysite/urls.py`?

Comment: @rawbeans just posted it check it out

Comment: add code snippet instead of images

Comment: What version of Django are you using? 2.0?

Comment: @rawbeans yes 2.0.1

Comment: Hmm, I just created a new project with the same setup as yours under Django 2.0 and it is working fine

Comment: @Water Malone that's the point that I saw many people doing it and its fine with them I dont know why it's not working with me

Comment: @Water Malone check please the second picture look to from . import views , it takes import as a module not the ( . ). i guess that is the problem and i dont know how to solve it can you help please??

Comment: @Encode.to.code That is not an issue. That is just how your text editor (Atom) is highlighting the code. It will not effect how the code runs.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your polls urls in `mysite/urls.py`

Add this to the `urlpatterns` in `mysite/urls.py`

```
url(r'^', include('polls.urls', namespace="polls")),
```

Also make sure to add the following line to `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`:

```
'polls',
```

Comment: i updated the question that shows what i did in mysite/urls.py , so please can you check if what i have done is just like what you said?? and thank you

Comment: do you have `polls` added to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py? @Encode.to.code

Comment: no I dont have it in installed_apps how should I add it tho?

Comment: Yes try adding it

Comment: @Encode.to.code everything in your setup looks fine. However, the app does not seem updated. Maybe you haven't saved one of the files? or refreshed the server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177225/discussion-between-rawbeans-and-encode-to-code).